# How to disable line numbering in taglist window in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have recently set the option

```
:set relativenumber
```

in my `.vimrc`, and now when I open Taglist or NERDTree windows, the lines in those buffers are also numbered.

Is there a way to disable line numbers in the Taglist and NERDTree buffers (but keep them in all other buffers)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both NERDTree and TagList buffers have specific file types that help
in distinguishing them from all the others. It is especially useful in
auto-commands, since one can execute a command whenever the
file type of a buffer is set to a specific value.

In this case, we need to switch off the `relativenumber` option
whenever the file type of a buffer is `nerdtree` or `taglist`:

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree set norelativenumber
:autocmd FileType taglist set norelativenumber
```

(Note that the `relativenumber` option is local to a buffer and,
therefore, is switched off only in the current buffer.)

Comment: Thanks that does just what I wanted.